# Old user producing low quality answers? What can we do?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

There is [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/20969/ajay-dubedi) user who looks like he has been around for the last couple of years, and in last few days he has been constantly producing low-quality answers, which are being downvoted by all. The [quaterly reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/459/quarter/salesforce/2019-01-01/20969?sort=reputationchange#20969) is being shown as -50. I tried commenting on certain answers but to no avail, am not sure what other options we have?

I get that the user has the intention to help, but low-quality posts are just affecting the quality of SFSE. I understand this behavior if he/she was a new user, but for old user it seems bit alarming.

Comment: I've also tried several times to get this user's attention via comment and I've never seen him respond to anything. The lack of response, selection of questions to answer, and high level of copying and pasting are a very odd pattern.

Comment: Yes, the link only answers seem really odd with a user that has been around here enough to earn a few thousand rep. I can't really see what else to do other than posting comments on the threads.

Comment: I took the liberty of locating this poster on the Trailblazer Community and observed the same pattern. While he sometimes *does* write more in-depth answers, a majority of his posts consist solely of search result links and a canned sign-off. For that reason, and as we've seen here too, his answers are sometimes non-sequiturs or simply repeat content that's already present in the question.

Comment: I think one of the Moderators should reach out to him personally and make him aware of how to answer and so on .

Comment: I raised a mod flag since he didn't seem to respond to comments. Was marked as helpful, but the user is still posting a lot of low quality answers.

Comment: Looks like the [user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/20969/ajay-dubedi) is suspended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm all in for downvoting his code-dump posts. However,  I am curious to know, does it take x number of his posts to be downvoted enough for SFSE to disable him from Posting? Is there a number?

I do know that the same occurs when Posting questions, if you have enough of them with enough downvotes, then, you are banned from posting new questuons unless you delete or edit your posts.

Comment: [StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) indicates that there is a metric (*partially* based on downvotes) and that the details aren't public.

Comment: Yes users can eventually receive an answer ban. I think it's related to percentage of existing posts (including deleted), so it would be very hard for an established user to trip this sensor. I may try suspending them for a short time to see if they respond.

Answer (score 4):

As counter-intuitive as it may sound, have we left any of this user's recent answers alone long enough for him to come back the next day and see the negative attention?

For a few days now, I've been inspecting this user's new answers and flagging as appropriate, but that doesn't seem to be having an effect.

About the only things I can think of here to explain this are:

1. This user does still care about contributing to various Salesforce communities, but isn't seeing our feedback because all of their answers are being flagged and deleted while they're sleeping.
2. This user doesn't care about contributing any more, and is spamming to increase traffic/page rank for their own blog (or other blogs, or some other self-centric goal)

I'd suggest holding off on flagging these answers, and just downvoting for a couple of days (say, until 2019-4-6?) to gauge whether or not this user is still motivated by our internet points.

If there's no response or other indication of behavior change, then I don't think there's much we can do aside from downvoting, flagging, and deleting until the system imposes a ban.

Comment: [This non-deleted answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255286/disable-multiple-input-field/255301#255301) received comments from both you and me, Derek, and the user made no response at all over the last four days. I'm personally struggling to assume good faith with this user, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @DavidReed I've seen about 3 or 4 non-deleted answers this year for this user that have corrective comments. With about 4 - 8 new answers coming daily, that just might not be enough signal. I think it's less about assuming good faith at this point and more testing to see if a strong enough negative reaction prompts any reaction or change. To be able to gauge that, we'd need to leave the bad answers downvoted and undeleted for long enough to garner some attention (and also spread over enough people and time so the system doesn't issue voting corrections).